# How to convert pdfstamper to byte array

Tags: arrays, byte, itext, pdfstamper

In my application, i need to read the existing pdf and add barcode to the existing PDF and pass it to output stream. here the existing pdf is like template. I am using iText jar for adding barcode.

I want to know the possibilities of converting `PdfStamper` object to byte array or `PdfContentByte` to byte array. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is unclear. I assume that you want to write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of to a `FileOutputStream`. There are different examples on how to do that on the iText web site.

See for instance the [FormServlet](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=170) example where it says:

```
// We create an OutputStream for the new PDF
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// Now we create the PDF
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
```

Then later in the example, we do this:

```
// We write the PDF bytes to the OutputStream
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(os);
```

If you want a `byte[]`, you can simply do this:

```
byte[] pdfBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

I hope your question wasn't about writing a `PdfContentByte` stream to a `byte[]` because that wouldn't make sense: a content stream doesn't contain any resources such as fonts, images, form XObjects, etc...