# Open PDF file download without store in drive

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

My requirement is to force the system to open the PDF file without storing in server or client system. I am using java, jsf, iText. But I've not succeeded so far. Any help?

Comment: That is trivial on the server side, but what kind of clients are we talking about? Web browsers and their plugged-in PDF viewers? You can hardly prevent them storing temporary copies somewhere.

Comment: Server-side, you can create the PDF file in a stream (i.e. no PDF file will be stored in the server's filesystem). However, unless you set up some DRM system, the file will have to be downloaded client-side in order to be viewed (even if it's downloaded in a temp folder, it'll be on the client's filesystem anyway).

Comment: Need to open pdf file browser or acrobat reader. not save in server or using predefine file path.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered a day ago here: [How to convert pdfstamper to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385446/how-to-convert-pdfstamper-to-byte-array/26388239#26388239)

I didn't mark your question as duplicate, because your question and that question may seem different at first sight, but the answer to both questions is identical:

See for instance the [FormServlet](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=170) example where it says:

```
// We create an OutputStream for the new PDF
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// Now we create the PDF
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
```

Then later in the example, we do this:

```
// We write the PDF bytes to the OutputStream
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(os);
```

As you can see: we do not store the PDF using a `FileOutputStream` (no file is stored on the server), but we store the file in memory using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. We then write the bytes to the `OutputStream` of the response object.

This example is taken from a book that also contains a JSP example: http://itextpdf.com:8180/book/helloworld.jsp

However, the book lists a substantial number of reasons why it's a bad idea to use JSP to create PDF. As a JSP developer, you know that JSP should never be used to create files in a binary format. PDFs are binary files, hence: you should write a Servlet to create a PDF, not a JSP file.